# Adding CAShapeLayer to UIButton but it appears under the border line

Tags: ios, uibutton, cashapelayer

I want to add a red dot to the border of a UIButton. My current code for adding a dot is like so:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUp()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.borderColor = normalBorderColor.cgColor

        let redDotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        redDotLayer.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 30, y: -3.5, width: 8, height: 8), transform: nil)
        redDotLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(redDotLayer)
    }
```

However when I add the red dot it appears **under** the border line. I need it to be on top of the border line.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your approach.

1. For example just consider adding subview to parent `UIView`, subview always stays inside the parent it can't be added above the parent.
2. Same scenario applies to `CALayer` . You can't `addSublayer` above parent layer.
3. As an exception,

> Unlike views, a superlayer does not automatically clip the contents of sublayers that lie outside its bounds rectangle. Instead, the superlayer allows its sublayers to be displayed in their entirety by default. However, you can reenable clipping by setting the masksToBounds property of the layer to YES.

as per apple documentation sublayer can go beyond parent visible region, but not above the parent.

3. Even below methods won't help us.

   `- insertSublayer:atIndex:`

   `- insertSublayer:above:`

   `- insertSublayer:below:`

> - addSublayer:
>     Appends the layer to the layer’s list of sublayers.

## Solution

Draw another `CAShapeLayer` around the button.

Answer (score 0):

CALayers may just draw the border around itself last. I think the easiest solution for you is just be to draw the border in a separate layer so that you can control the ordering.

```
override func setUp() {
  super.setUp()

  let borderLayer = CALayer()
  borderLayer.borderWidth = borderWidth
  borderLayer.borderColor = normalBorderColor.cgColor
  layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

  let redDotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  redDotLayer.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 30, y: -3.5, width: 8, height: 8), transform: nil)
  redDotLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
  layer.addSublayer(redDotLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I was unable to use another layer as a border so I've used another `UIView` as a border.
An important part is to set the border `UIView` `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false so the responder chain would pass it to the `UIButton`:

```
let borderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
borderView.backgroundColor = .clear
borderView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.18).cgColor
borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 19
// Dont't forget to set it to false or else the button won't work
borderView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```